# Merging selected files from similar branches after one was rebased

Tags: git, merge, rebase

While I was working on `feature1`, at commit point `A` below, I was asked to build another mod onto it. Let's call it `feature1+`. This means the graph looks like this:

```
master: o---o---o---o---o
             \
feature1:     o---e---e---e---O---A
                                   \
feature1+:                          o---c---c---X
```

Now I want to merge `feature1+` back onto `feature1`, but I realise the changes between files existing at `X` and `A` are minimal; there are two new tracked files in the `c` commits.

Along the way, I began consolidating the commits on `feature1`, rebasing the `e` commits into a single one `o'` to reduce the number of commits back on master in the end. I believe the effective graph is this:

```
master: o---o---o---o---o
             \
feature1:     o---o'---O---A
               \     
feature1+:      o---e---e---e---O---A---c---c---X
```

However, this means `feature1+` dumps the `e` commits onto `feature1` as well when I run:

```
git checkout feature1
git merge feature1+
```

Which gives me:

```
master: o---o---o---o---o
             \
feature1:     o---o'---O---A---e---e---e---O---c---c---X
```

I want to add the `c` commits without reintroducing the `e` ones. In other words, merge it back into this:

```
master: o---o---o---o---o
             \
feature1:     o---o'---O---A---c---c---X
```

How may I do so? I've tried to just `checkout` the new files from `c` when in `feature1` at A, but of course this gives the files without retaining their history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While on branch: `feature1` checked out at A:

doing `git cherry-pick feature1+: A .. X` should result in the desired tree

```
master: o---o---o---o---o
             \
feature1:     o---o'---O---A---c---c---X
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer, suggested by @nevyn on the #git channel in Freenode IRC, was to `cherry-pick` the desired commits onto `feature1` (the docs suggested this but I was probably just afraid to try):

```
git checkout feature1
git cherry-pick c # the first c
git cherry-pick c # OK, the second one, I didn't think ahead THAT far.
git branch -d feature1+ # warns + gives the correct command for an unmerged branch
```